# Showing $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ are not continuous for $f(x,y)=xy\sin\frac {1}{x^2+y^2}$.

Tags: functions, multivariable-calculus, continuity

> Consider function $f:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R $ by 
>   $$
> f(x,y)=
> \begin{cases}
> xy\sin(\frac {1}{x^2+y^2})~~~~;~~~(x,y) \neq (0,0),\\
> 0~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~;~~~(x,y) = (0,0).
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   show that
>
> $1.$ $\partial f/\partial x$ and $\partial f/\partial y$  exist at $(0,0)$.
>
> $2.$ $\partial f/\partial x$ and $\partial f/\partial y$ are `NOT` continuous at $(0,0)$.
>
> $3.$ $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$.

I was able to show (1), but how should I go about (2)? Should I find the limit of $\partial f/\partial x$ at $(0,0)$ from each direction?

And for (3), I have a feeling I should use the result from (1) and (2) to show it, from my notes I see a theorem that basically states if $\partial f/\partial x$ and $\partial f/\partial y$ both exists AND is continuous at $(0,0)$ (or any other point), then (3) is true. Since (2) violates the condition, what other method can I use to show differentiability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $2$) Observe that for $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ we get
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=y\sin\left(\tfrac1{x^2+y^2}\right)-\tfrac{2x^2y}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\cos\left(\tfrac1{x^2+y^2}\right)\qquad\text{and}$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=x\sin\left(\tfrac1{x^2+y^2}\right)-\tfrac{2xy^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\cos\left(\tfrac1{x^2+y^2}\right)$$

As $(x,y)$ tends to $(0,0)$ on the $x$ axis, i.e., with $y=0$, we get 
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,0)=0,\quad x\neq 0$$
However, if we take the sequence $\mathbf{x}_n=(x_n,y_n)=\left(\tfrac1{\sqrt{4n\pi}},\tfrac1{\sqrt{4n\pi}}\right)$ we see that
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(\mathbf{x}_n)&=\frac1{2\sqrt{n\pi}}\sin(2n\pi)-2(2n\pi)^2(4n\pi)^{-3/2}\cos(2n\pi)\\
&=\sqrt{n\pi}
\end{align*}
So, $\partial f/\partial x$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$ since tends to two different values as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ on two different paths (sequences). Similarly it can be proved that $\partial f/\partial y$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$.